# How can I track multiple images with RealityKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have an AR app that tracks AR Reference images and overlays them with other images. The problem is that to each reference image I need to overlay a different and specific image. Here is my code:

This is where I am tracking the AR Reference images:

```
    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
        
        guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else {
            print("No images available")
            return
        }

        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 4
        
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

And here I am rendering the overlaid images:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        
        let node = SCNNode()
        
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: 2/2, height: 0.9/2)
            
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "Frame 1.png")
            
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            planeNode.position.y = 0.3
                            
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }
        return node
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        guard let imageAnchor = anchors.first as? ARImageAnchor,
              let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else { return }
        
        let entity: ModelEntity = retriever(name: imageName)
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)
        
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
    
    func retriever(name: String) -> ModelEntity {
        
        let entity = ModelEntity()
        
        switch name {
            case "orange": entity = orangeEntity
            case "banana": entity = bananaEntity
            default: break
        }
        return entity
    }
}
```